# Google Classroom Students API PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: api, google-classroom

I'm using G-Suite google classroom API and I'm trying to add student to a course, I have enabled all administration permission to my account, I made sure I have all required scopes requested in the access token but still I'm getting PERMISSION_DENIED

```http
POST /v1/courses/<courseId>/students HTTP/1.1
Host: classroom.googleapis.com
Content-length: 70
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>

{
  "profile": {
    "verifiedTeacher": true,
   },
  "userId": "studentId"
}
```

[API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students#Student)

So My Question is why I'm still receiving this error? how to find the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Two minor things: Are the two consecutive `/` in the url are correct and I hope the actual Bearer token is in place when you perform the actual request and has just been removed from the posted code.

Comment: yes the // is /courseId/ and access token is just removed from posted code.